# Selecting only distinct record from table in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have table with following records;

```
ID | NN  | MBL  | IC | OTHER
---+-----+------+----+------
1  | 123 |      |    | ac
2  |     | 544  |    | dc
3  |     |      | 524| df
4  |527  |      | 124| ff
5  |123  |      |    | tr // duplicate NN of ID 1
6  |     | 544  |    | op // duplicate MBL of ID 2
7  |     |      | 124| ii // duplicate for IC ID 4
```

When querying with select I need just records with single entry, skipping second occurrence,

```
select 
    ID, NN, MBL, IC, OTHER 
from 
    TABLE1  // this should return only one entry of any NN, MBL and IC
```

How do I get this, I cannot use distinct for multiple columns and I also need ID and OTHER column to display in select query

Expecting result like this:

```
1  | 123 |      |    | ac
2  |     | 544  |    | dc
3  |     |      | 524| df
4  |527  |      | 124| ff
```

Comment: Which one of the duplicates do you want? The one with the lower ID?

Comment: no maters any of them

Comment: @Rene updated to question as result expected

Answer (score 1):

You can use the analytical function ROW_NUMBER() to calculate ranks over each column you want and filter only these rows with rank = 1.

Here is an example:

```
WITH testdata AS (
    SELECT 1 AS ID, 123 AS NN, NULL AS MBL, NULL AS IC, 'ac' AS OTHER FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, NULL, 544 , NULL, 'dc' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, NULL, NULL, 524 , 'df' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 527,  NULL, 124, 'ff' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, 123,  NULL, NULL,  'tr' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 6, NULL, 544, NULL,   'op' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 7, NULL, NULL      , 124, 'ii' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT *
  FROM(SELECT ID,
              NN,
              CASE WHEN NN IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NN ORDER BY ID) END AS NN_RANG,
              MBL,
              CASE WHEN MBL IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MBL ORDER BY ID) END AS MBL_RANG,
              IC,
              CASE WHEN IC IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY IC ORDER BY ID) END AS IC_RANG,
              OTHER
         FROM testdata
      )
 WHERE NN_RANG = 1
   AND MBL_RANG = 1
   AND IC_RANG = 1
;
```

Hope it helps.